# Python Selenium - How to setup firefox remote webdriver? (gecko error)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

Below is the current code I have been trying to use to run tests on a Firefox node I have set up.

```
def setUp(self):
    self.wd = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='http://10.0.1.226:4444/wd/hub',
        desired_capabilities= DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
    )
```

I keep getting the error:

> WebDriverException: Message: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property.

How do you fix this? I have looked online in other threads and cannot find any python syntax to resolve this problem, please help.

EDIT: I have set up the environment variable to the geckodriver and restarted my machine, the script still gives the error:

WebDriverException: Message: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property

Is the syntax above correct? Do I need to set up the capabilities to factor in the firefox marionette thing?

Comment: try brew install geckodriver

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the geckodriver path in your `PATH`?

You can add the path to the driver on Mac by typing the following into a terminal window:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/geckodriver
```

On Windows you can search for `View advanced system settings` and then click on the button that says `Environment Variables`. Click on `PATH` > `EDIT` > `NEW` and add the path to geckodriver.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have just added the path to the geckodriver to the Environment Variables and now when i run the script it falls over on the "desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX" line and provides the error message: "WebDriverException: Message: None" Is there a specific format in which I should've added the environment variable?

Comment: I don't have my mac with me, so I can't provide an example for macOS, but on my Windows machine I've entered it as: `C:\Users\Marcel\Drivers\geckodriver`. I added the folder containing the driver, not the actual driver

Comment: I've tried editing the PATH to use both C:\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe and C:\geckodriver neither seem to be working properly.